# What is limit $\frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus

I know that the answer to the limit
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2}$$
 is $1/2$ but I want to know how to solve it with my hand.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion

Comment: Use either series expansion or L'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: Use the taylor expansion: $e^x=\frac {x^0}{0!}+\frac {x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\ldots$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: L'Hopital's Rule is easier.

Comment: Without hands: you recognize that the negative terms cancel out the first two terms of the Taylor development of $e^x$, and the next coefficient is $\frac1{2!}$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint
$$e^x-x-1=\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+...$$
Using the Taylor series for $e^x$.

Answer (score 2):

**L’Hospital’s Rule:** When you have limit in $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ form, differentiate the numerator and denominator and then apply the limit

For this problem, apply L’Hospital’s Rule twice.

Comment: More generally, it can be an expression of form $\frac a \infty$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ or $a=\pm\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use series of $e^x$.
A more quick way is using l-hopital rule

If putting the value in the limit gives $\frac{0}{0} or \frac{\infty}{\infty}$ then we can use this method. Simply differentiate the numerator and denominator until it is no more $\frac{0}{0} or \frac{\infty}{\infty}$ (as the case may be) form.

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2} = \lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^x-1}{2x}$ Again apply the rule.

$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^x}{2}=\boxed{\frac{1}{2}}$